# How do i flag a change in a JSON object using polymer and passing data from javascript then render some child elements

Tags: javascript, json, object, polymer, rerender

I'm generating a JSON with a random set of X's and O's and trying to plot them into a simple grid using a custom element in polymer. When I first open the page everything runs fine and i see a different grid each time. I've also added a button on an index.html page that regenerates the JSON with a new set of X's and O's, but the polymer element wont flag an event change or update its child elements with the new data.

It only seems to be an issue with my JSON object, because if i change it to a string, i get a change notification each time...

i have written a simple "forceDB.js" script that generates the JSON and passes it to the polymer element with `.setAttribute('layout', data)` how do I notifiy the change to polymer and have all the children elemtents of my polymer script update?

The JSON object looks like this

```
let data = {
  "a1":"",
  "a2":"",
  "a3":"",
  "b1":"",
  "b2":"",
  "b3":"",
  "c1":"",
  "c2":"",
  "c3":""
};
```

my polymer script side of the element looks like this...

```
enter code here
<script>
  Polymer({
    is:'grid-layout',
    properties:{
      layout: {
        type: Object,
        reflectToAttribute : true
      },
      observers: 'layoutChanged(layout.*)'
    },
    setLayout: function(newdb){
    console.log('new - ' + JSON.stringify(newdb));
    this.set('layout', newdb);
    },
    layoutChanged: function(changedthing){
    alert("Layout Changed!");
    },
  });
</script>
```

I think that I may be missing a key point in polymer or maybe I'm doing something wrong. But I have a simple X's and O's game that I'm developing to try come to grips with polymers data binding principals and seem to be falling short where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the layout property needs:

```
notify: true
```

And it might be helpful to see how you are data binding the layout property to the child elements in the HTML.

Comment: I have tried to use notify: true, however that doesn't seem to work. I've use a `document.getElementById(...).setLayout(data);` executed by pressing a button on index.html from the forceDB.js  with `data` being the new set of X's and O's JSON object. I found a work around by implicitly setting each key value as a parameter through the `.setLayout({a1: data.a1,a2:data.a2...})` however this still doesn't make sense as a full JSON doesnt render but an implicit change to each value does?

Comment: Are you data binding the layout to the child elements using the brackets in the html, Or just setting the attribute manually on each change with set?